# block QUERY_STRING in htaccess other then secified

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^ts=.*$ [L]
RewriteRule   ^$ index.php? [L]

RewriteRule   ^index\.html$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^(set_language)-([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\.html$  index.php?language=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\.html$  index.php?g1=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\.html$  index.php?g1=$2&province=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\.html$  index.php?g1=$2&g2=$4&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\.html$  index.php?g1=$2&g2=$4&g3=$6&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

First two lines are for blocking the QUERY_STRING. Mainly on my page links are like

```
[TEXT]-[NUMBER].html
[TEXT]-[NUMBER]-[TEXT]-[NUMBER].html
```

etc. There is one link from contact form that containg GET value

```
?ts=[NUMBER]
```

I realy dont know how to block all QUERY_STRING's except the one from last link. Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `how to block all QUERY_STRING's except the one from last link`

Use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^ts=[^&]*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Almost works, but now it lets pages only if there is "ts" in query. As i mentioned only one page has it. So basicly there are two cases: links with no QUERY (after "?") and only one link with "ts" in QUERY. Is this "!^(ts=[^&]*)?$" what i'm lokking for?

Comment: Still not as expected, for excample:
`calling "/" - works fine`
`calling "/?ts=123" - works fine`
`calling "/some_text-12.html" - throws error`
`calling "/some_text-12.html?ts=123" - throws error`
above shouldn't throw errors and what should throw error is for example: `"/some_text-12.html?some_random=value"` and those are the ones i want to get rid of.

Comment: Are you sure `"/some_text-12.html?ts=123"` throws error? Can you try a new browser to test?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure, i've checked it on few browsers. Your last code seems to work as expected :) so thank You very much for Your help. Would You be so kind to explain or point where can i find info about "ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS". I didn't find any good source of information so far :/

Comment: `ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS` is set by `mod_rewrite` once an internal rewrite has occurred. I added that condition to avoid applying this rule after your other rules.